# WSGI file not loading Python Flask file on Apache 2.4 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: python, windows, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run a Flask script that queries an SQLite database and displays a Rest API only for inside the network.  It is going to be served on Windows Server 2012 running Apache 2.4 with mod_wsgi.  I'm also using Python 3.7.

The error I'm getting in the error log is:

```
File "D:/sites/cifsearch/website/web.wsgi", line 7, in <module>\r, referer: 
     http://IP Address/  from app.py import app as application\r, referer: 
     http://IP Address/  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'\r, referer: http://IP Address/
```

web.wsgi is on the same directory as app.py

This is what I have written on web.wsgi. I copied and pasted this from what I could find on google as I'm still very new to this.

```
import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig (stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,'/')

from app.py import app as application
```

I also commented out:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run()
```

in app.py as per this site:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/.
But I don't think the request is even getting that far.  I'm suspecting, it's probably path related or permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is not set up as a package, so the import in your wsgi code gives you the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Put your application in a directory called e.g. `myapp` and add an `__init__.py` file to the directory containing

```
from .app import app
```

to make it a package.

Your directory structure should look like this:

```
web.wsgi
myapp/
    app.py
    __init__.py
```

Then change your `import` line in the wsgi file to

```
from myapp import app as application
```

Comment: OMG that work!  Thank you so much.  

I also updated the line in WSGI to point to where app.py was moved to. 

    sys.path.insert(0,'D:/sites/cifsearch/website/myapp')

Comment: You are very welcome! Good luck and lots of fun with your project!